# How do I improve performance when constructing a grid in Angular?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, performance

Everytime the route changes (recordTab.Id changes) I have to construct a new grid with five columns and output it.
The following code generates the grid every route change

```
// used later in html code to generate five columns with *ngFor
this.columns = [0,1,2,3,4]
// the records are filtered based on the id
this.id = recordTab["id"];
//allRecords has 1300 elements in it
this.records= allRecords.filter(record => record.recordTabId == this.id); // filter by recordTabId

// construct grid with 5 columns 
// the maximum number of cells per column are 300
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
        this.grid[i] = [];
        this.grid[i] = new Array(recordTab["gridCells"]); // number of cells in a column
}

if(this.records){
   for(let record of this.records){
          // assigning record to its corresponding cell
          this.grid[record.column - 1][record.row - 1] = record; 
   }
}

// has maximum 5*300 entries
// 600 entries filled
// rest is empty to simulate empty cells
console.log(this.grid)
```

Now I am displaying the grid in the following way:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="column" *ngFor="let column of columns">
        <div class="cell" *ngFor="let record of grid[column]">
            <ng-container *ngIf="record">
                <div class="record checkboxes" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': record.categorie==1 ? record.rgbFarbeHex : 'white'}" [ngClass]="{'heading-container': record.categorie==1}">
                    <label [ngClass]="{'heading': record.categorie==1}" [title]="record.name" (contextmenu)="showRecordInformation($event, record)"> <span *ngIf="record.categorie==0"> &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="checkbox">  &nbsp;</span> {{record.name}}</label>                       
                </div>
            </ng-container>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the grid takes some time to show up for the grid with 5*300 entries and 600 actually filled entries. How could I improve the performance?
I dont think the css is the problem, that is why I dont show it. If it is necessary, tell me.

Comment: I think your problem is depends more on designing rather than code optimisation. Try to make pagination from server side  where you can control the things like this.

Comment: @ganesh045 Thank you for your input. All items has to be visible (you have to be able to scroll over all items), therefore pagination is unfortunately not an option. Can I somehow "lazy load" the items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [trackBy](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5). It will tell your ngFor to only rerender what changed based on what you are tracking. It's hard to tell if it can work in your case but there is no other solution since as soon as the array changes, angular loose track of what's going on and needs to render the *ngFor again.

It would look like that:

```
<div class="column" *ngFor="let column of columns; trackBy:trackByFn">

trackByFn(index, item) {
    return item.id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did not work. So, the main problem is the *ngFor? Could I theoretically pre filter all possible combinations (maximum 10 different recordTabIds => 10 different grids (just one grid is very big)) and create for every id its own container and control the visibility with *ngIf? So the array itself wouldnt change. Would that be a better or worse approach?

Comment: Try adding it to the your second ngFor, and the code I wrote might not work because you need to track something that exist in your object. If you are not sure what the problem is, try using a much smaller grid and see if it's still slow and if it is then you know the problem doesnt come from the rendering

Comment: It is much faster on smaller grids. So the main problem is to render all elements. What if the id is a composition of two different keys in the object? And I think it will not work because a lot of items are actually changing but I can test it. Thanks

Comment: If the id is the same it should be fine but it's not something I tested myself. Its never a good idea to render huge amount of data and expect it to be fast and responsive, you might need to rethink your architecture.

Comment: Yes I think that as well. thank you for your help!